Oracle 19c Error while installing on Oracle Linux Server 9.4
Encountering this error while installing Oracle 19c
Error in invoking target 'links proc gen_pcscfg procob' of makefile '/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/precomp/lib/ins_precomp.mk'. See '/tmp/InstallActions2024-05-30_02-55-30AM/installActions2024-05-30_02-55-30AM.log' for details.
this is my OS Oracle Linux Server VERSION="9.4"
any suggestion please ?
i've tried to install all the prerequisite in this link https://oracle-base.com/articles/19c/oracle-db-19c-installation-on-oracle-linux-9

See '/tmp/InstallActions2024-05-30_02-55-30AM/installActions2024-05-30_02-55-30AM.log' for details. Did you look at the log file? What did it say?
